# Steam not loading properly? [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: steam

Since I updated my system (was on march 30th I think), Steam has been really weird. Most of the time all pages are just blank , but then sometimes after a minute or two everything loads in , except the library. That is how it was for the last couple days , but when leaving steam open for like an hour yesterday , it fixed itself ? But after a restart it went back to being borked.

[a clip of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCgoy.jpg)

I already tried the standart things that come up on google:

-clearing the Steam browser cache

-opting in/out of Steam beta
-disabling hardware acceleration for the UI

... and some other stuff that didnt work.

The console just says

```
STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
```

over and over again.

I really dont have any Idea what to do from here , maybe one of you can help me

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259943/discord-and-steam-will-not-display-properly-ubuntu-20-04?rq=1 helps. Does not have an answer yet, but maybe one will come soon

Comment: Didn't find a fix yet, but as a temporary solution I can launch Steam by launching a game. Somehow that completly fixes the issue?